# Possible to use QUERY to combine multiple sheets in the same workbook?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a workbook that is used to track production outputs. There are a few main tab sheets (e.g. Main List, PDLine1, PDLine2, Daily Summary).

Main List is used to list out all the production orders, while PDLine sheets is used to track production orders in their respective production line. Daily Summary will list the total output of the day for each PDLine.

From the PDLine sheet, I actually generate a new sheet to track each production orders to measure their Daily Output (one order takes roughly about 3 - 5 days to be done).

Therefore, is it possible, that using QUERY function and app script, everytime I generate a new production order sheet, that sheet will be added into the QUERY function in the Daily Summary sheet?

I don't know if what I mentioned above make sense to you or not, but if you have an idea of how to do this, and willing to help, feel free to ask me to elaborate more.

Link to example spreadsheet:
[Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1isolENQ02fi52XKO9UMeChwrJyQmd35ufEPZ8kxAjSQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you share sample sheet

Comment: Hey @HMProduction, welcome to Stackoverflow! What you describe definitely seems to be possible to do. Could you please provide a minimal example of your sheet? (a few sheets with a few rows each should suffice). This way we can provide a tailored Google Apps Script solution for you. Cheers!

Comment: Hello. Sorry for getting back late. I've attached the link below, but I'm not sure it works or not, so I will add it into my question as well. Feel free to tinker around with the layout of the summary tab as well if needed. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1isolENQ02fi52XKO9UMeChwrJyQmd35ufEPZ8kxAjSQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need import range for sheet PDLine, you can use this one for each PDLine Sheet just change filter with your sheet:

```
={QUERY(JobList!A:P,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G where H='PDLine1'"),ArrayFormula( QUERY(JobList!H:O,"Select O where H='PDLine1'") ),ArrayFormula(QUERY(JobList!D:H,"Select D where H='PDLine1'")- QUERY(JobList!H:O,"Select O where H='PDLine1'") )}
```

And for Daysummary I test in mine:

In cell A4 I put:

```
=query({query(JobList!A10:O,"Select A,O where H<>'' ",-1),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:H,"Select H where H<>'' ",-1)="PDLine1",query(JobList!H10:O,"Select O where H<>'' ",-1),0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:H,"Select H where H<>'' ",-1)="PDLine2",query(JobList!H10:O,"Select O where H<>'' ",-1),0))},"Select Col1,sum(Col3),sum(Col4),Sum(Col2) where Not Col1='' group By Col1 LABEL Sum(Col3) '',Sum(Col4) '',Sum(Col2) ''",0)
```

and in E4 I put:

```
=query({query(JobList!A10:I,"Select A,I where H<>'' "),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:I,"Select H where H<>'' ")="PDLine1",query(JobList!H10:I,"Select I where H<>'' "),0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:I,"Select H where H<>'' ")="PDLine2",query(JobList!H10:I,"Select I where H<>'' "),0))},"Select sum(Col3),sum(Col4),Sum(Col2) where not Col1='' group By Col1 label sum(Col3) '',sum(Col4) '',sum(Col2) ''",0)
```

May be this can be used in script

```
function createQuery() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var myJ = ss.getSheets();
    var ShList=[];
    for (a=1; a< myJ.length; a++)
    {
      if (myJ[a-1].getSheetName().substring(0, 3)=='myJ')
        ShList.push (myJ[a-1].getSheetName()); 
    }
    var myQry='={';
    for (a=0; a<ShList.length; a++)
    {
      if (a>0) myQry = myQry + ",";
      myQry= myQry + "QUERY(" + ShList[a] + "!B8:C10,\"Select B,C\")";
    }
    myQry= myQry + '}';
    Logger.log(myQry); //put this to cell
    ss.getSheetByName('myRslt').getRange('A4').setFormula(myQry);
}
```

In yours may will be like this:

```
=query({query(JobList!A10:O,"Select A,O where H<>'' ",-1),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:H,"Select H where H<>'' ",-1)="PDLine1",query(JobList!H10:O,"Select O where H<>'' ",-1),0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:H,"Select H where H<>'' ",-1)="PDLine2",query(JobList!H10:O,"Select O where H<>'' ",-1),0))},"Select Col1,sum(Col3),sum(Col4),Sum(Col2) where Not Col1='' group By Col1 LABEL Sum(Col3) '',Sum(Col4) '',Sum(Col2) ''",0)
```

and in E4 I put:

```
=query({query(JobList!A10:I,"Select A,I where H<>'' "),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:I,"Select H where H<>'' ")="PDLine1",query(JobList!H10:I,"Select I where H<>'' "),0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(query(JobList!H10:I,"Select H where H<>'' ")="PDLine2",query(JobList!H10:I,"Select I where H<>'' "),0))},"Select sum(Col3),sum(Col4),Sum(Col2) where not Col1='' group By Col1 label sum(Col3) '',sum(Col4) '',sum(Col2) ''",0)
```

May be this can be used in yours

```
function createQuery() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var myJ = ss.getSheets();
    //Below you will use the ss as your spreadsheet and myJ as your Sheets
    //But may be different in yours,
    //ShList is stringlist to store your sheetname that matchs to your criteria
    var ShList=[];
    for (a=1; a< myJ.length; a++)
    {
      //If your sheet prefix is 'JO' use below, if others you can change it
      //substring(0, 2) is depend on your sheet name that will be included
      //in myQuery later
      if (myJ[a-1].getSheetName().substring(0, 2)=='JO')
        ShList.push (myJ[a-1].getSheetName()); 
    }
    var myQry='={';
    for (a=0; a<ShList.length; a++)
    {
      if (a>0) myQry = myQry + ",";
      //You must change A8:G10 to your actual condition, may be you can use getLastRow() first, you can use select * if all column define will be included
      myQry= myQry + "QUERY(" + ShList[a] + "!A8:G10,\"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G\")";
    }
    myQry= myQry + '}';
    //Please check your logger.log content, myQry must be success first
    Logger.log(myQry); //put this to cell
    //Change myRslt to your destination sheet that you will store your query
    //Change A4 to your destination cell
    ss.getSheetByName('myRslt').getRange('A4').setFormula(myQry);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason I shouldn't be using importrange? I just used that because I think it's easier where I can just import a range based on a query. Plus, the information on JobList will not be edited as it is only used to list out jobs.

Comment: it's never mind, but I afraid the traffic from user to google will give more

Comment: To your newly edited answer, I think the formula that you provided is very useful. But my main problem isn't with the formula. Instead, I wanted to know if there are anyway using a script, I can add Sheet into my query formula. For example, my current formula is `=query{JO1!A8:G8, JO2!A8:G8 "Select Col...."}` . Then after running the script another sheet will be added and it changes to `=query{JO1!A8:G22, JO2!A8:G22, JO3!A8:G22 "Select Col...."}`.

Comment: I think you can use setFormula in google script, for example sheet.getRange(row, column).setFormula("=Query(.....)");

Comment: And for adding sheet in query, you can combine some action, 1st sheets list (with ss.getSheets()) and lastRow, and then create query string with them.

Comment: I will make the last formula like this: ={QUERY(myJ1!B8:C10,"Select B,C"),QUERY(myJ2!B8:C20,"Select B,C"), ....and so on} or you can use your formula

Comment: That's the idea that I had, but I don't know specifically how to add the range into the formula. setFormula (existing formula in a cell + JO1!A8:G22) or somewhere along those line, but I don't know the exact script to use, nor do I know if this is remotely possible.

Comment: In my script the range is constant, B8:C10, you must set as you required, and my target sheet begin with myJ so I used if with condition myJ[a-1].getSheetName().substring(0, 3)=='myJ', for yours must change to substring(0,1)='J', but it will use all sheet with prefix J will be a target

Comment: Why am I only getting an empty array string after running the script? It doesn't register any cells as reference in the formula inserted into myRslt

Comment: myRslt is sheet in mine, so you must change the myRslt as your destination query, your adding sheet is J01 or JO1? and can you inform me the log content after run script?

Comment: if JO1, please change the expression of myJ[a-1].getSheetName().substring(0, 3)=='myJ' to myJ[a-1].getSheetName().substring(0, 2)=='JO'

Comment: OK I add new to the answer

Comment: your script is wrong: if (myJ[a-1].getSheetName().substring(0, 1)=='myJ1'), because you will check 1 letter begin from first letter, (0,1) means get 1 letter begin from letter m, but you must change to substring(0, 4)=='myJ1' or because the suffix 1 is index, so I will use substring(0, 3)=='myJ'

Comment: And your sheets don't have myJ1, only myJ

Comment: May I edit your sheets and script for your purpose?

Comment: Sure, be my guest.

Comment: For vertically, you can change "," in (if (a>0) myQry = myQry + ",") to be ";"